# uwp xbinding fail with converters

Tags: c#, uwp, xbind

I have to converters to use with Texblocks and a Slider in UWP app.
When using Binding everything works fine, but after changing to x:Bind the converter stops working. The properties are being updated correctly and if I remove the Converter (from the textboxes) I see the values being updated (but without the proper format).

Perhaps someone could help me to change the converters code to be compatible with x:Bind (I already tried but I cant find a solution).

The Properties:

```
Position = TimeSpan
Duration = TimeSpan
Duration.TotalSeconds = double
```

The Slider control needs the Position converted to double.
The Textblock control need the Position converted to string with the proper format.

XAML code Slider Control

```
<Slider Name="PositionSlider" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="10" 
Value="{x:Bind ViewModel.Position, Mode=TwoWay, Converter={StaticResource TimeSpanToSecondsConverter}}" 
Maximum="{x:Bind ViewModel.Duration.TotalSeconds}"/>
```

TextBlock control

```
<TextBlock Margin="10" Text="{x:Bind ViewModel.Position, Converter={StaticResource TimeSpanToStringConverter}}"/>
```

The Code for the "TimeSpanToSecondsConverter"

```
public sealed class TimeSpanToSecondsConverter : IValueConverter
{
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
var timeSpan = value as TimeSpan?;
return timeSpan?.TotalSeconds ?? 0.0;
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
var seconds = value as double?;
return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds ?? 0);
}
}
```

The Code for the "TimeSpanToStringConverter"

```
public sealed class TimeSpanToStringConverter : IValueConverter
{
public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
var timeSpan = value as TimeSpan?;
return timeSpan?.ToString("mm\\:ss");
}

public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
{
throw new NotSupportedException();
}
}
```

Thank you.

Comment: if it is inside a itemscontrol, use Bindings.Update() inside 'ContextChanged' event, you can also try using UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged

Comment: Have you solved your issue by calling `Bindings.Update()` method?

Comment: No I did not. When I'm using x:Bind I do not use DataContext, instead I use a local Property that maps to my viewmodel, my understanding of Bindings.Update() is to be used with DataContextChange event.